# Trying to get image layover to link to the right page

Tags: jquery

Here is a link to the site 
http://urbanacountryclub.clubhouseonline-e3.net/The_Scene/The_Scene_(2)

In the footer, when i click on one of the three 3 links , it always redirects to the first ( golf) . I have linked there properly in the html but i think the java script is causing this.

Here is the code :

```
<script>
  $(function(){ 
$(".nav-btns").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
  });

</script>
```

Comment: `$(this)` refers to .nav-btns, the container, not the individual buttons

Comment: @zfrisch , you are right . So i guess i should be targeting each container which would be nav-btn ?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refers to .nav-btns, the container, not the individual buttons

```js
  $(function(){ 
$(".nav-btns").click(function() {
  console.log(this);
  return false;
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-btns">
<div class="nav-btn">
<div class="nav-image"><a href="/Golf/Golf"><img alt="Golf" src="/SiteDesign/Images/btn6.aspx"></a></div>

<div class="nav-text animated fadeInUp"><a href="/Golf/Golf">GOLF</a></div>
</div>

<div class="nav-btn">
<div class="nav-image"><a href="/Dining_(1)"><img alt="dining" src="/SiteDesign/Images/btn1.aspx"></a></div>

<div class="nav-text  animated fadeInUp"><a href="/Dining_(1)">DINING</a></div>
</div>

<div class="nav-btn">
<div class="nav-image"><a href="/Weddings/Weddings"><img alt="wedding button" src="/SiteDesign/Images/btn7.aspx"></a></div>

<div class="nav-text  animated fadeInUp"><a href="/Weddings/Weddings">WEDDINGS</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Change the selector to grab `.nav-button`

```js
$(function(){ 
$(".nav-btn").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
  return false;
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-btns">
<div class="nav-btn">
<div class="nav-image"><a href="/Golf/Golf"><img alt="Golf" src="/SiteDesign/Images/btn6.aspx"></a></div>

<div class="nav-text animated fadeInUp"><a href="/Golf/Golf">GOLF</a></div>
</div>

<div class="nav-btn">
<div class="nav-image"><a href="/Dining_(1)"><img alt="dining" src="/SiteDesign/Images/btn1.aspx"></a></div>

<div class="nav-text  animated fadeInUp"><a href="/Dining_(1)">DINING</a></div>
</div>

<div class="nav-btn">
<div class="nav-image"><a href="/Weddings/Weddings"><img alt="wedding button" src="/SiteDesign/Images/btn7.aspx"></a></div>

<div class="nav-text  animated fadeInUp"><a href="/Weddings/Weddings">WEDDINGS</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: doing this would only allow me to click on the actual text link. I tried to put the class of each container and i think that did the trick. Thank you for your help . Really appreciate it.